# Start conversation on google home from other device

Tags: dialogflow-es, grpc, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-assist-api

We have a Google Home device, for example, the Google Home mini. After that we have created a dialogflow conversation. So the basic conversation looks as followed:

```
User: Hey Google, talk to water log.
Google Home: Hello, did you know that you have to drink 3 litres of water each day.
User: Hey Google, talk to water log that I have drunk 500ml water today.
Google Home: You have drunk a total of 500ml water today.
```

That works fine. We are trying to achieve that the Google Home/Assistant starts the conversation, or that we can remotely send a command to the Google Assistant to start a conversation on the Google Home (from another device than the Google Home) and continue the conversation. So for example:

```
Google Home: Hey [user], Did you drink some water today? 
User: Yes, I have drunk 300ml today.
Google Home: You have drunk a total of 300ml water today.
```

That's where we get stuck. We have tried to do the following, broadcast a message with the grpc/google assistant SDK. The first part is broadcasted, but when you say something back it doesn't know the context of the intent.

How can we start a conversation and that the user can talk back to the google home?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm trying to achieve exactly the same thing...

Answer (score 1):

Having the Assistant initiate a conversation on its own is not possible, presumably because that would quickly be abused by developers. There are however several ways to keep users engaged via reminders, notifications etc., check out the [User engagement](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/overview) section of the docs for that.